# Android onClickListener for a whole layout with a different onClickListener for an internal view

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a simple LinearLayout that consists of a `TextView` and an `EditText`. The behaviour that I'd like to achieve is to be able to click on the EditText and handle it like normal, but treat the encompassing LinearLayout as a button that launches a new activity.

So for example, if the user clicks the space around the button in the view, a new activity is launched. If the user clicks on the EditText, then the keyboard appears and the user can populate the EditText.

Here is the simple onClickListener for the layout, which simply states that it has been clicked:

```
LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            System.out.println("layout clicked");
        }
    });
```

And the EditText has an OnFocusChangeListener that will simply state when it has gotten focus:

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    System.out.println("EditText clicked");
}
```

Results:

-When the user clicks on the layout, the result "layout clicked" is correct
-When the user clicks on the edittext, the result is "layout clicked" followed by "EditText clicked", which is not correct. I'd like to ignore the linear layout's onClick event for this case.

Comment: AFAIK any view can have onClickListener, even EditText. Indeed: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html You should try to use it first, instead of OnFocusChangeListener

Comment: For purposes of my app, the EditText uses different onEditorActionListeners and onFocusChangeListeners, so although simply using an onClickListener on the EditText DOES work to solve the problem, it doesn't allow me to use those two other listeners that I have set.

Comment: Do you mean that setOnClickListener() conflicts with onEditorActionListeners and onFocusChangeListeners? That's strange, I wouldn't expect that. For clarity - is it problem in your code, or setting setOnClickListener disables your onEditorActionListeners/onFocusChangeListeners handlers?

Comment: May this work for you?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19724608/1028256 and note that with return value of onTouch() you can handle if default  listeners will be applied

Comment: @Mixaz yes, that is correct. Setting the onClickListener conflicts with the onEditorActionListener and onFocusChangeListener. Just the onClickListener gets activated if I include it.

Comment: Then you could try to use onTouch() instead, as I suggested before, and return 'false' to allow the touch event being processed with default listeners. I mean that onTouch listener will not conflict withonEditorActionListener and onFocusChangeListener. If you return 'true' then the event will be consumed (I think so) and no other listeners will be called, including onClickListeners if any

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it, I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a FrameLayout that contains a LinearLayout containing the TextView and place the EditText above the LinearLayout. This way you will not need to change anything about the listeners.

So it would be like this:

> ```
> <FrameLayout
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="@string/hello_world" />
> </LinearLayout>
>
>
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/editText1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="200dp" />
>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

Note: use margins to adjust the position of the EditText

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should work, although it isn't the cleanest solution.

Declare a `runnable` that should be executed when the layout is clicked.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable layoutPressed = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        // LAYOUT CLICKED
    }   
};
```

Then start this runnable in your layout `onClickListener`.

```
LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            handler.postDelayed(layoutPressed, 100);
        }
    });
```

Cancel the runnable in `onFocusChange`.

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(layoutPressed);
    // EditText clicked
}
```

So whenever you click the editText, the onClick of your layout will get called first, but the actions will get cancelled when onFocusChange of the editText is called.

When you click the layout, onClick will get called and will execute its actions with a 100 msec delay.

You might have to modify the delay of the runnable.